# I need a simple, number guessing game using Perl. What am I missing or what needs to be changed?

Tags: perl

The user can only have a max of 8 tries, if they reach the 8 the loop should end. I am new to learning Perl so it can only be basic Perl concepts. When I try to run it, it does not let me input any guesses and is a never ending loop. It loops errors which are down below. I'm assuming that I'm missing something but not sure what that is.

```
Use of uninitialized value $counter in numeric le (<=)
Use of uninitialized value $guess in numeric gt (>) 
Use of uninitialized value $guess in numeric lt (<) 
Use of uninitialized value $guess in concatenation (.)
```

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my ($guess,$target,$counter);

$target = (int rand 100) + 1;

print "Welcome to k Perl Whole Number Guessing Game!\n";

print "Please enter a number between 1 and 100 and I will tell you if the number you're trying to guess\nis higher or lower than your guess. You have up to 8 chances to uncover the number.\n";

my $counter <= 8;

print "Enter guess #$counter: $guess";

while(($counter <= 8) || ($target == $guess))
{
    if($guess > $target)
    {
        print "Your guess, $guess, is too high. Try again.";
    }
    if($guess < $target)
    {
        print "Your guess, $guess, is too low. Try again.";
    }
}

if($target == $guess)
{
    print "Congratulations! You guessed the secret number ($target) in $counter tries!"
}

elsif(($target != $guess) && ($counter > 8))
{
    print "I'm sorry, you didnt guess the secret number, which was $target."
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line? `my $counter <= 8;`

Comment: I was just stating that the count for the loop can not go over 8. Maybe I don't need that included in this code since it's in the while?

Comment: @toolic's question was leading you to think about where you initialise the variable vs where you check the variable. Concentrate on the former :-)

Comment: "_stating that the count for the loop can not go over 8_"  -- OK. So, `$counter` is a variable, (very crudely speaking) a name for a place in memory where some value is held.  A thing that you can assign to or retrieve a value from.  Can't "_state_" conditions like that.

Comment: Use `<STDIN>` in order to read from console

Comment: (I'm surprised that Perl lets you get away with `my $counter <= 8;` with only warnings. I'd expect that to be an outright syntax error, so that it doesn't compile.  There's probably some legitimate use that's similar enough so that the parser can't resolve it ... but I don't see what that would be)

Comment: You never actually read what a user types in! That doesn't magically come into your program; need to retrieve it from wherever it is. In this case, you want to read console input, and in Perl `STDIN` stands for the filehandle for "standard input" stream (always opened for us), and we usually read from a filehandle using `<>`. So, `my $guess = <STDIN>; chomp $guess;` (that `chomp` removes the newline from the end of `$guess`, which you always get when reading user input).

Comment: So you'd say `print "Enter guess #$counter: ";`, where `$counter` has been initialized to `1`  earlier (not `<= 8` !), so `my $counter = 1;`, and will be incremented every time in the loop, and then `my $guess = <STDIN>; chomp $guess;`. Then you get into your loop, and in there you'll need to read from `STDIN` again (to retrieve a new guess they type in and update your `$guess` variable) in the loop if the user's guess fails and you want to give them another chance.

Comment: I haven't checked your logic and/or conditions, or any detail. Example: that `$target == $guess` is backwards, no? You want to continue the game while they're _not_ guessing correctly so `$target != $guess`

Comment: @zdim it's perfectly legal to have a `my $foo` declaration within a larger statement, and that's what that is interpreted as: `(my $foo) <= 8`

Comment: @zdim useless in this context of course, since scalars will always be undef on declaration, but could be used in a more complicated expression to do something useful.

Comment: @Grinnz Yeah, that's what I'm thinking ... but, the declaration _alone_ in a middle of an expression, I'm having trouble seeing how it can be used for anything. Perhaps it's just too close to call, for something a _little_ different that indeed can be used.  Or perhaps it's a little crack in the parser ... `=` is OK (In an expression, for example) so certain kinds of operators are then just given a pass ... just because, hey it's legal?

Comment: @Grinnz  ... I guess it's just too much, too many possibilities, if it's legal, so you can only warn. (I still can't see how it can be useful for anything, in principle: it introduces a variable (name) at that scope, OK ... but it's `undef` so what's the benefit? it can be introduced later, when used, just as well.)  anyway... I think that you're right -- it's legal, period.

Answer (score 4):

You was on right track, I made a small change to your code

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my ($guess,$target,$try,$counter);

$target = (int rand 100) + 1;

print "Welcome to k Perl Whole Number Guessing Game!\n";

print "
Please enter a number between 1 and 100 and I will tell you
if the number you're trying to guess is higher or lower than
your guess. You have up to 8 chances to uncover the number.

";

$try = $counter = 8;

while( $counter ) {
    print "You have left #$counter guesses: ";

    $guess = <>;
    chomp $guess;

    print "Your guess, $guess, is too high. Try again.\n"
            if($guess > $target);

    print "Your guess, $guess, is too low. Try again.\n" 
            if($guess < $target);

    $counter--;

    last if $target == $guess;  
}

$counter = $try - $counter;

print "Congratulations! You guessed the secret number ($target) in $counter tries!"
        if($target == $guess);

print "I'm sorry, you didnt guess the secret number, which was $target."
        if($target != $guess);
```

Comment: This worked! However, my professor only allowed "my ($guess,$target,$counter);" as what I could use. I didn't think to mention that so I appreciate you commenting so I at least have a idea of how to do number games.

Comment: You can follow logic of your original post and write to the screen **try #** it also will work. I guess that professor would not allow **constant** as number of allowed tries to guess. Probably **$target** should be **$secret** as it is not known to the _player_. Your original code was missing code for **input** from the player - I showed one of the many ways to **collect** input and compare it with **secret**.